# Current and next month posts

Tags: posts, wp-query

Thanks for reading firstly.

I am coding a site that requires 3 post titles for the current month and 3 post titles for the next month (upcoming events)!

I am struggling to get this to work.  I am using wp_query to do this but I cannot get to work at all!

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Just to expand on this as I might not have made myself clear!

I want to be able to show this months 3 events / posts and next months 3 events / posts - How would I do this? Please help as I am going slightly insane..

Cheers!

This is the code for the current month 3 blog title:

```
                <p class="blue"><?php the_time('F') ?> <span class="small">Events</span></p>

                <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>


                        <div id="date">

                            <span class="date">         
                                <?php the_time('j') ?>
                            </span>
                            <br />

                            <span class="month">
                                <?php the_time('M') ?>
                            </span> 

                        </div>  <!-- end date -->
```

```
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <hr>


    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: A sample of the code you have tried should be very valuable in order to help you. Also, clarify what you are trying to do. "the site needs 3 post titles for the next month" is very unclear.

Comment: OK, Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I just want to show the latest three posts titles using time stamps.

Comment: Can you see my code now? Thanks!

Comment: "... posts from next month" - do these posts have future publish dates or do you use some custom field to store this date?

Comment: These do have future published dates for example May 3rd for this year. Not using custom fields  - just posts! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query_post for up to 3 posts for the current month:

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$current_month = date('m');
$args = array(
    'year'     => $current_year,
    'monthnum' => $current_month,
    'order'    => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, any chance you could tell me how to get 3 posts for the next month please :)  Thanks again!

Comment: @Ben Ask a new question on that.

Comment: Thanks for this, I already have and it has been answered here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142086/posts-for-next-month/ Thanks for your help :)