# Posts for next month

Tags: posts, wp-query

How would one get posts that are set to 'future' to display in a loop? I am trying to figure out how to get posts that are in the future months.  So if we are in April I want to display posts for May.  Think of it as a coming up posts.

I have been looking at

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters and I have been looking at this too:

http://joshpress.net/blog/using-new-date-queries-wordpress-3-7/

Something like this but for next month's post:

```
<?php
//get an array of the date 2 days from now
$twodayslater = getdate( current_time(‘timestamp’) + 2*DAY_IN_SECONDS );
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'before' => array(
            'year'  => $twodayslater['year'],
            'month' => $twodayslater['mon'],
            'day'   => $twodayslater['mday'],
        ),
        'inclusive' => false,
    ),
    'post_status'         => 'future'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

but have had no luck!

Thanks,

Ben.

Comment: Post your code, please, even if it doesn't work. That will make it easier to help.

Comment: Hi there, I do not have code for this at the moment but I am working on it.  Thought I would ask here first to see if anyone had the answer :)

Comment: That is a good way to get down-voted here. [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) already has anything you seem to be after. Maybe you just didn't know how to use the parameters...

I would do this by means of a `date_query`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => array(
        'publish',
        'future',
    ),
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => strtotime( 'now' ),
            'before' => strtotime( '+1 month' ),
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // or a high number, if you want to pre-fetch post meta data
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    // now you can use the_title(), the_content() etc.
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**// EDIT**:
If you want to display posts from the (whole) next month only, then you might try the following date query:

```
$date = strtotime( '+1 month' );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => array(
        'publish',
        'future',
    ),
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => date( 'Y', $date ),
            'month' => date( 'n', $date ),
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // or a high number, if you want to pre-fetch post meta data
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have marked this as the answer.  Cheers for all of your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post_status' => 'future',
   'showposts' => -1
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
$this_month = date( 'n' );
$next_month = $this_month + 1;
foreach( $posts_array as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );

    $post_month = get_the_date( 'n' );

    if( $post_month == $next_month ):
        //show what you want about each post
    endif;

endforeach;
```

Depending on where you want it in your template, you could use WP_Query in stead of get_posts function http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

If you ask in the comments, I can set up an example of that for you.

Comment: Hey Douglas, Thanks for this. What I am after is to write a functions / loop that checks the current month and then gets the posts for the next month.  So something like this:  if is 'Jan' get all posts for 'Feb' else 'Display no post for next month' - Something along these lines!  Cheers :)

Comment: Hey again, Thank you for your code. This was great and I have copied it for another project I can use it on. Thank you to all who help :)

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Thank you I did and I have expanded it how I wanted it perfectly! Thanks to a wonderful community - I'm sure I have more questions to ask :)